# How to customize default theme of radio button in android?

Tags: android, android-radiobutton

i want to change default theme of radio button to custom but it's not changing the theme. please help me out

styles.xml

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:radioButtonStyle">@style/radionbutton</item>
</style>

<!-- custom style -->
<style name="radionbutton"
     parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.RadioButton">
    <item name="android:button">@drawable/radiobutton_drawable</item>
</style>
```

radiobutton_drawable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@mipmap/radio_unselected" >
</item>
<item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@mipmap/radio_selected">
</item>
```

Comment: see my answer bellow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, i found answer by myself

I just create custom layout and add to ListAdapter object

radiobuttonlayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/checkedTextView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:checkMark="@drawable/radiobutton_drawable"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:text="New CheckedTextView"
android:padding="@dimen/dp10"
android:textColor="@color/white" />
```

Java file code

```
ListAdapter listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>    (context,R.layout.radiobuttonlayout,aryStrLockscreens);
    listview_lockscreen.setAdapter(listAdapter);
```

It's worked for me.

Answer (score 11):

Declare custom style in your styles.xml file.

```
<style name="MyRadioButton" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">  
  <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/indigo</item>
  <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/pink</item>
</style>
```

Apply this style to your RadioButton via android:theme attribute.

```
<RadioButton  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:checked="true"
    android:text="Radio Button"
    android:theme="@style/MyRadioButton"/>
```

only if your activity extends AppCompatActivity

Answer (score 3):

Sure you can do it in the parent AppTheme just do the following:
First you will Use the `MaterialTheme` as your parent theme:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.*">
```

Then create your `RadioButton` style in `res/values/styles`

```
<style name="Widget.App.RadioButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.CompoundButton.RadioButton">
        <item name="buttonTint">@color/white</item>
       //put any thing here
</style>
```

Add it to Parent `AppTheme`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.*">
<item name="radioButtonStyle">@style/Widget.App.RadioButton</item>
</style>
```

Then Use it in your layout like:

```
<com.google.android.material.radiobutton.MaterialRadioButton
            android:id="@+id/rb"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="hi"
            />
```

for more details about theming [Theming RadioButton](https://material.io/develop/android/components/radiobuttons#theming-radio-buttons)

Answer (score 1):

The **radiobutton_drawable.xml** has a missing `</selector>` tag in the end.
Plus you should do this to your radio button-

```
<RadioButton android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
           android:id="@+id/radio"
           style="@style/radionbutton"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to apply individual style to radio button

```
<RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        style="@style/radiobutton_drawable"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: But here... i have taken radio button in listview.

Comment: This is how ..  ListAdapter listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice,aryStrLockscreens);
        listview_lockscreen.setAdapter(listAdapter);

Comment: still you can apply to row which you inflate in ListView i.e Listview Item

Comment: aryStrLockscreens is string array

Comment: Which method do i need to use to set style?

Comment: why dont you just create your own layout then instead of using the default. in case you dont want to change the style while inflating

Comment: you have to write cutsom adapter by extending ArrayAdapter Check  this :https://devtut.wordpress.com/2011/06/09/custom-arrayadapter-for-a-listview-android/

Answer (score 0):

You could add this to your styles.xml

```
<style name="Widget.Styles.Radio.RadioButton" 
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/ANY_TYPOGRAPHY_STYLE</item>
</style>
```

**ANY_TYPOGRAPHY_STYLE** is for example:

- *TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Caption* if you are using the Material theme
- *TextAppearance.AppCompat.Caption* if you are using AppCompat theme.

---

- OR any typography style you have created

Example:

```
<style name="TextAppearance.TypographyStyles.Body2" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Body2">
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/poppins_regular</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/poppins_regular</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
</style>
```

And use the radio button style as a style for the **MaterialRadioButton** or **RadioButton**

```
<com.google.android.material.radiobutton.MaterialRadioButton
            style="@style/Widget.Styles.Radio.RadioButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TEXT"/>
```