# Android RadioButton shows only text, not the actual button in device emulator

Tags: java, android, android-radiobutton

I have a group of radio buttons displaying fine in my XML design window, but in the emulator (and on my actual device that I installed the app on) it only shows the button text and not the button.

[image: screenshot]

Here is the XML file for this activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Question1">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/errorView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:text="@string/error_msg"
        android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:text="@string/my_gender_is"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/gender_group"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_male"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="@string/male"
            android:textColor="#636363"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radio_female"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/female"
            android:textColor="#636363"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

    </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/nextPage"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:fontFamily="@font/segoeuil"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
    android:paddingTop="-9dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:text="@string/next"
    android:textAlignment="gravity"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textSize="26sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/background</item>

    </style>

    <!-- No title bar theme -->
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/background</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@color/primary_text_material_dark</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

It looks fine in the preview but on my device and in the emulator is seems to exclude the radio buttons.

Comment: Everything seems good.

Comment: I think it has something to do with your app theme. Can you check your syles.xml file. Because your code is running fine on my device

Comment: @Umair I've added my styles.xml as well as my manifest. I am using a custom theme, but I'm not entirely sure how they work. I can post my colors in the theme editor if it helps

Comment: @ConnorS Ok let me check but no need for the manifest :). Can you tell me one more thing if your activity is extending `AppCompatActivity` or `Activity`.

Comment: @Umair Thank you for the help. I am extending AppCompatActivity

Comment: @ConnorS Please try my answer and check if it works for your or not. Because it seems like your styles.xml is alright.

Comment: I will try it. I should mention they used to show up, until I employed the custom theme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using in a wrong way I guess use it as following:

First declare your custom styles in `styles.xml` file like this:

```
    <style name="MyRaidoButton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.RadioButton">
    <item name="colorAccent">#0091ea</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimaryDisableOnly">#f44336</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat</item>
</style>
```

Once the style is done now all you need is to assign that particular style to your radio button or group like the following:

```
<RadioButton
android:id="@+id/products"
. . .
android:theme="@style/MyRaidoButton"/>
```

For more info take a look at the following links:

http://www.zoftino.com/android-ui-control-radiobutton

[How to customize default theme of radio button in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35150890/how-to-customize-default-theme-of-radio-button-in-android)

Comment: Just tried this, didn't work. As mentioned above, the buttons used to show up until I started using a custom theme.

Comment: @ConnorS there are only two themes in your styles.xml file. Can you post that specific custom theme ?

Comment: would that be in themes.xml?

Comment: @ConnorS you should know it :). Normally all custom themes you make are in styles.xml file/folder.

Comment: Lol this is where my break down is happening I think. I wasn't sure how to properly implement a theme, so I just defined a bunch of colors in the color.xml file, and used theme editor to make this: https://i.imgur.com/lAdT0xl.png

Comment: The NoActionBar theme in styles.xml is the one I am using

Comment: @ConnorS lol you implemented the theme directly. and now can't find it :P. Can you undo it and implement it like this ? http://www.zoftino.com/android-ui-control-radiobutton   or like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35150890/how-to-customize-default-theme-of-radio-button-in-android   :)

Comment: Looks like it worked! The zoftino article had a good solution. I needed to create a new style that had Widget.AppCompat.CompoundButton.RadioButton as it's parent, and make each radio button use that as its theme

Comment: @ConnorS you should **accept** and **upvote** this answer for doing your help.

Comment: Yes absolutely. However, would you mind updating the answer with that detail? The current contents of the answer did not solve the problem. It was the zoftino article that explained making a new theme with the proper parent

Comment: @ConnorS yes I have updated my answer. Glad I could be of help. Happy coding :)